# Considerations for moving a lightning node to new hardware?

Tags: lightning-network, full-node

Lightning nodes get rated. Amongst other factors, uptime is a big one of them.

If I want to upgrade to new hardware, what are the steps necessary to do so? Let's for simplicity assume, that I use umbrelOS.

- I have my private key ready.
- I install umbrelOS on my new system.
- I set it up with the same private key.

...Done?

Will all my channels automatically work again? Will the new node find them on its own? Do I need to backup anything (I know that I can backup channels)?

**And most of all: Will I get a penalty in terms of uptime for the time the node is offline?**